# APIGEE local error - messaging.adaptors.http.flow.ServiceUnavailable

Tags: apigee

I'm a newbie in apigee. I tried to configure apigee local to map
this url

```
http://localhost:10002/welcome
```

to **the site is hosted in docker**

> http://localhost:9090/welcome

Somehow, not sure what went wrong, im getting this error

```
{"fault":{"faultstring":"The Service is temporarily unavailable","detail":{"errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.ServiceUnavailable","reason":"TARGET_CONNECT_CONNECTION_REFUSED"}}}
```

Checked on this this [article](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/errorcatalog/mp-runtime-errorcatalog), not entirely sure what need to do, could anyone advise.

These are the map that configured in APIGEE side.

*Local Development>apiproxies> apiproxy> proxies> default.xml*

```
<ProxyEndpoint name="default">
  <HTTPProxyConnection>
    <BasePath>welcome</BasePath>
  </HTTPProxyConnection>
  <RouteRule name="backend">
    <TargetEndpoint>backend</TargetEndpoint>
  </RouteRule>
</ProxyEndpoint>
```

*Local Development>apiproxies> welcome-backend-map>targets>backend.xml*

```
<TargetEndpoint name="backend">
  <HTTPTargetConnection>
    <URL>http://localhost:9090/welcome</URL>
  </HTTPTargetConnection>
</TargetEndpoint>
```

Comment: What do you mean by Apigee local error? Are expecting Apigee to resolve the endpoint hosted on your local machine? That won't be possible. The endpoint should be available on the internet for Apigee to be able to consume.

Comment: @Ram , we can setup the local Apigee, im referring to this artricle, https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/local-development/overview, which is possible to configure local

Comment: Did you try to access an site/api on the internet?